# А можно ли рекламировать кому-то?

Tags: стилистика, управление

> «НОУ МИКРОВЭЙВ!»  – так они рекламируют **вам** своё заведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*«НОУ МИКРОВЭЙВ!» – так они рекламируют **вам** своё заведение.*

А мне кажется, что такая фраза вполне допустима.
Товары для беременных нужны **не всем.** Их и рекламируют - кому? - беременным женщинам (например, в консультации). Высшие учебные заведения рекламируют образование - кому? - выпускникам школ. Получается, что в рекламе есть ***определенная направленность*** на какую-то категорию людей или отдельного индивида.

*Она туда пару раз сама с ним ходила, и Ходасевич **рекламировал ей** местную дешевизну и качество товаров.*
[**Вояж с морским дьяволом**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=_MPSSrQTS3oC&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=ujDELXFV7R&sig=H2ROWHlpge_xRSk9kXLi4AljyqE&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijvuna__nTAhXHXiwKHWoGAjg4FBDoAQhEMAU#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE&f=false)

*Это ужасы, так называемый антихеппи-энд, как **рекламировал мне** ее продавец.*
[**Тихий ужас**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=de6MAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=uunfh5uTq6&sig=Tll5xznBXiv6_PmHemlcQZ5UcMA&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWr_-mgPrTAhXSJSwKHSwsDjE4FBDoAQhJMAY#v=onepage&q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE&f=false)

*Режиссер фильма Скотт Дерриксон замечательно **разрекламировал мне** роль Кецилия.*
[**интервью с Мадсом Миккельсеном**](http://www.ok-magazine.ru/stars/interview/47127-mads-mikkelsen-rol-zlodeya-v-doktore-strendzhe-stala-samoy-slozhnoy-za-vsyu)

*Они разъезжали по Кавказу, и этих новых хозяев белые всячески **рекламировали** **перед населением.*** [перед населением = кому? - населению]
А.Первенцев, "Кочубей"

Из интернета:
*Как производителю с дурной репутацией **рекламировать народу** качественный товар?*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Благодарю за правку. Каюсь, прошляпила.

Answer (score 1):

Функция рекламы - привлечение всеобщего внимания. Поэтому дополнение ВАМ становится лишним. Здесь наблюдается что-то вроде лексической избыточности.

Comment: Реклама может иметь адресат, явно или неявно обращаться к определенной категории населения. Вопрос я понимаю так: грамотно ли в принципе говорить, что некто рекламирует что-то **кому-то**

Comment: Я бы ответила: да, неграмотно в принципе говорить "рекламировать кому-то".